# How can I fix unity webgl not breaking after loading my game?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I try to share games to my friends by building them in WebGL but I always seem to have some kind of issue. This time I have an issue where I get a big error code thing after my games loads in a browser. I tried resetting all the player settings in the build settings and then turning the right stuff on like compression off and setting icons and such but it still doesn't work!

Is there something that I can do to fix this? Here is the error I get.

````
abort(150) at jsStackTrace@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:16316
stackTrace@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:16487
abort@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:748
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[47559]:0x7251b5
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[28244]:0x41152d
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[44698]:0x6b668f
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[36736]:0x55c193
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[47372]:0x724721
unityFramework/Module.dynCall_iiiii@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:421691
invoke_iiiii@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:307255
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[45389]:0x6d307c
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[44793]:0x6bc546
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[8077]:0x14c331
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[8075]:0x14c225
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[2047]:0x759c7
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[14685]:0x218e83
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[14684]:0x2185ef
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[14683]:0x218560
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[18610]:0x28d681
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[15137]:0x227d68
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[19328]:0x2aa671
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[18778]:0x29350d
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[18778]:0x29351f
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[18768]:0x2930db
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[18760]:0x2926ec
@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js line 2 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[46243]:0x6f1bba
unityFramework/Module.dynCall_v@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:428496
browserIterationFunc@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:150370
runIter@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:153443
Browser_mainLoop_runner@http://localhost:8080/Build/BattleAttackThingy.framework.js:2:151905```
````

Comment: I've came across this kind of problem too, for me it was a bit random, but it seems that certain versions of unity better support WebGl than others... Try using the latest stable version maybe...

Comment: @kyysel ok thank you I will try another version of unity and see if that works